# Why is my edmx file not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a database first ASP.NET MVC 5 EF6 project. I'm using VS2015 CE. When I change my database (SQL Server 2012), I then go to VS to update my edmx file like this:

- Double click on the edmx file in the solution explorer
- In the edmx file right click on a blank space and select the option 'Update Model From Database'
- I click on the button 'Finish'
- I Rebuild the solution

When I have a table with the columns ID, Column1, Column2 and I changed Column2 into Column2Changed, my edmx has a model with ID, Column1, Column2, Column2Changed instead of ID, Column1, Column2Changed.

Also, when I change the datatype for a column, this change is not applied in my edmx.

Answer (score 23):

This is a well-known problem with Entity Framework.

"Update Model from Database" continues to be a hit-and-miss affair.  Sometimes it works, often it doesn't.

Personally, I just delete the "updated" table from my .edmx file, then re-add it.  Then it seems to be work okay.

Comment: Wow, this is still a problem? I had this type of issue about 3 versions ago, one of the reasons I stopped using EF, but I assumed they would have fixed it by now.

Comment: *(Very quietly)*  I know it's no longer supported, but for basic database tasks, I still use "LINQ to SQL" rather than EF.  It just *works*.  But it's not supported, so don't do it.  But it works.  But don't do it.  Unless you want to.  But you shouldn't.  But you can.  But shouldn't.    I'll go and vote myself down now.

Comment: This isn't a 'problem', per se... I'm pretty sure the EDMX update process is _designed_ to not remove properties in the model after the database is changed. After all, you can have properties in the model that don't map to database tables. It's up to the programmer to decide that the (orphan) property should be removed.

Comment: Btw, I'm having the same problem with my .edmx file today.  I've changed the type of a particular field, and can't get the .edmx to reflect this change.  Even worse, it throws errors about other tables (which haven't changed) and when I give up, "Undo checkout" and revert to the original .edmx file in TFS, I *still* get these errors. Aahhhh!!!   "LINQ to SQL".    I don't care how outdated and unsupported it is... it just works.

Comment: ⚠️ Be careful when table have more than one FK to the same table.This make EF start calling the references as NameTable, NameTable1, NameTable2 so if any changes in structure, those could generate references that make EF change this naming order making your code compile but no with the logic you expected before

Comment: The same solution is suggested at: https://medium.com/@cjab/rebuilding-the-model-from-the-database-in-visual-studio-325d29c30729

Comment: I found that it is **really important** that the model designer (.edmx) is ***saved*** in between deleting and re-adding a table. This forces a code generation step to run. Not doing that may lead to a scenario where the designer shows new columns but the generated classes are not updated. After that if you try to use the `Run custom tool` command your classes are all gone, and if you don't do versioning or backup, it's not going to be fun.

Comment: Adding on to what @Marc.2377 has said, the edmx diagram will be modified but upon saving it runs a script that generates the model classes

Comment: i had the same issue and that was the last time i go with database first approach. however this is not the solution but may help you... i did the database/table changes(alter) from the visual studio server explorer instead of sqlserver managment studio.... and if  anybody do that in wpf project and local database beware of release/debug/project-itself databases

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me :

1.Build the project after updating EDMX file.

2.Right click your .tt file in solution explorer.

3.Select "Run Custom Tool" option.

This will update the .tt file.

Comment: I would also rebuild after running the custom tool.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you selecting the objects from Update tab

Answer (score 1):

When faced with this issue, i solved my by change the username and password...so i would say, make sure you have a valid connection string in your edmx

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue on a number of occasions.  For simple problems I've edited the edmx file by opening in the code editor ( Open With... > Source Code (Text) Editor ).

Locate the table by looking for by searching for EntityType Name="your table name".

Typically I see an entry that doesn't look right, delete it, save and close the file.   Open the edmx the usual way and refresh the model and Presto problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

After updating or refreshing and not getting expected results. 
I worked as follows:
1. I added procedure without importing it. 
2. I opened edmx with text editor and added my return types having complex type like other already present in it.
3. added all values like other procedures had.

That solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not logical but when We add empty table to Edmx, it is not added. If Adding a table with some records, will fix the problem.

Fix: Allways when an error occurred, when you open edmx in notepad, errors shows, maybe you dont have primary key and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
I updated the edmx model and then clicked Save button in edmx designer.

It seems like the code for all modified entities (views, tables, etc) is regenerated only on Save.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue. The most reasonable solution could be to delete .edmx file and to regenrate it. Keep in mind that you should always try to update model first if nothing work then do what I just said.

Comment: there is nothing new in this answer compared to the existing answers

Comment: Deleting the whole .edmx file it's impractical and could incurred in unexpected errors. It's completely not recomended.